# Can't find element in headless phantomjs 2.1.1 with Selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am running following code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",     "C:/Softwares/selenium/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capability);
        driver.get("https://facebook.com/");         
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Administrator");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("12iso*help");
        System.out.println("Enter usrname as: "+driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getText());
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_q")).click();                     
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());   
    //driver.quit();
```

This works as expected.
But now I tried using headless chrome browser using phantomjs
code:

```
WebDriver driver;
        File file = new File("C:/Softwares/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");             
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        caps.setCapability(
                                PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                                "C:/Softwares/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe"
                            );
        //caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"});
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);


        driver.get("https://facebook.com/");         
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Administrator");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("12iso*help");
        System.out.println("Enter usrname as: "+driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getText());
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_q")).click();                     
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
```

This shows me an error.

```
Error screenshot is: Mar 20, 2017 6:28:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: C:\Softwares\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe
Mar 20, 2017 6:28:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 42545
Mar 20, 2017 6:28:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--web-security=no, --ignore-ssl-errors=yes, --webdriver=42545, --webdriver-logfile=C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\Headless\phantomjsdriver.log]
Mar 20, 2017 6:28:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO  - 2017-03-21T01:28:29.851Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 42545
[INFO  - 2017-03-21T01:28:30.400Z] Session [b0d2ce50-0dd5-11e7-b70e-830369ea41ad] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":false}
[INFO  - 2017-03-21T01:28:30.400Z] Session [b0d2ce50-0dd5-11e7-b70e-830369ea41ad] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2017-03-21T01:28:30.401Z] Session [b0d2ce50-0dd5-11e7-b70e-830369ea41ad] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"windows-10-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2017-03-21T01:28:30.401Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: b0d2ce50-0dd5-11e7-b70e-830369ea41ad
Mar 20, 2017 6:28:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Page title is: Welcome to Facebook
[ERROR - 2017-03-21T01:29:08.179Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1490059748124

  phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'email'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"30","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:42545","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"email\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/b0d2ce50-0dd5-11e7-b70e-830369ea41ad/element"}}
Command duration or timeout: 30.20 seconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:420)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at test2.main(test2.java:37)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:142)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'email'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"30","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:42545","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"email\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/b0d2ce50-0dd5-11e7-b70e-830369ea41ad/element"}}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'WINDOWS-CPRD7P5', ip: '15.146.51.224', os.name: 'Windows NT (unknown)', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I am sure, url is opened properly as it is showing the page title. But can please anybody help why phantomjs is unable to find the elements on the page. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide the following info: 1. What is your objective? 2. What are you trying to do? 3. Debug your code and update where are you exactly stuck.4. Provide a proper snapshot of the error.

Comment: Post the html code around the element you are trying to locate, and I might be able to help you using xpath

Comment: What is your objective? Check feasability of headless testing of my project, 2. What are you trying to do? whatever I can do in UI, can I do the same in headless mode. 3. Debugged, - headless mode is unable to find the element, By.id("email")), please check html code for user name in facebook login page. i m trying the same element, hence not posting it here. Error screenshot is updated in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code:
(It is to be noted in both the Sysout the Title will be same as the login fails, so driver gets the same title)

```
File src = new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("Administrator");
driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("12iso*help");
driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", seleniumBrowserDriverPath);
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability("locationContextEnabled", true);
caps.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", true);
caps.setCapability("browserConnectionEnabled", true);
caps.setCapability("localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled", true);
caps.setCapability("locationContextEnabled", true);
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
    seleniumBrowserDriverPath);
PhantomJSDriver driver = new  PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```